# Python get abs() function to dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dict

```
cassa_negativa=dict()
cassa_negativa['Banche c/c ordinario']=[min(0,v) for v in liquidity.get('Saldo Finale')]
```

I want to apply abs() function to get postive value from negative one.

How could I get it?

Comment: `abs(min(0,v))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
   cassa_negativa['Banche c/c ordinario']=[abs(min(0,v)) for v in liquidity.get('Saldo Finale')]
```